# Iteratively apply a function to each pair of points in a given matrix

Tags: r, loops, iteration, apply

I have a function that estimates angle between two points `p1` and `p2` in 2D Euclidean space.

```
angle <- function(p1,p2){
  dot.prod <- p1%*%p2 
  norm.p1 <- norm(p1,type="2")
  norm.p2 <- norm(p2,type="2")
  theta <- acos(dot.prod / (norm.p1 * norm.p2))
  return(as.numeric(theta))
}
```

Then I need to iteratively apply function `angle` to pairs of points in `allPoints`. I need to select each 5th point, e.g.

```
Pair 1: 
  p1: allPoints[0] 
  p2: allPoints[4]
Pair 2:
  p1: allPoints[4] 
  p2: allPoints[8]
```

How can I do this?

```
angleSummary <- function(allPoints)
{
  # ???
  a <- angle(p1,p2)
  return(quantile(a, seq(0.2, 1, by = 0.20)))
}
```

Comment: How is ```allPoints``` structured? Could you provide the output from running ```dput(allPoints)```?

Comment: Nit: there is no angle between two points. There is an angle between two *vectors* with coordinates as defined. Oh, and by the way,  there is no index "zero" in `R` . You probably should read up on the fundamentals before getting zinged by things like that.

Comment: Agree with Carl, apparently working on more basic stuff could help you move forward. However, on the precise point you are asking about, you can play with expressions such as `t(combn(seq(0,16,by=4),2))` to get all the possible pairs.